# Why is NASA proposing an EMEJ (MEGA) trajectory for Europa Clipper instead of EEJ?

Tags: launch, trajectory, gravity-assist, jupiter, europa-clipper

A [launch service request](https://beta.sam.gov/opp/a494208ffa454df5b6f1b25e58f86c5c/view) was recently put out for Europa Clipper to do a flyby of Mars on its way to Jupiter. How is that a better trajectory than an [EEJ](https://trajbrowser.arc.nasa.gov/traj_browser.php?NEAs=on&NECs=on&chk_maxMag=on&maxMag=25&chk_maxOCC=on&maxOCC=4&chk_target_list=on&target_list=Jupiter&mission_class=oneway&mission_type=rendezvous&LD1=2024&LD2=2025&maxDT=7.0&DTunit=yrs&maxDV=10.0&min=DV&wdw_width=-1&submit=Search#a_load_results), similar to Juno?

> Launch Vehicle Performance: The launch vehicle shall deliver a minimum
> 6065 kg Europa Clipper spacecraft (SC) with Mars-Earth-Gravity-Assist
> (MEGA) trajectory characteristics as follows: C3 value of
> 41.69km2/sec2 and a DLA range of 30-32 degrees.
>
> Launch Period: Europa Clipper will be launched during a 21-day launch
> period beginning October 10, 2024 and ending on October 30, 2024.

[image]

It seems like the presentation was in a [Europa Clipper presentation](http://file:///C:/Users/tuvas/AppData/Local/Temp/pappalardo%20presentation_ec%20caps.pdf). The trajectory seems to be as follows.

[image]

Comment: I think the answer is that the Mars flyby replaces a deep space maneuver that would otherwise be required, but I haven't found a great proof for this.

Comment: The image for your simulation contains what I think is important text; Earth departure C3 = 25.5 km²/s². Am I reading it right, and is an important aspect of your question why they are requesting a higher C3 launch than seems necessary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like the biggest difference is the ability to avoid a 700 m/s deep space maneuver. That is required for a Juno style trajectory. The Mars flyby provides enough delta-v that this deep space maneuver isn't required.

In order to support the EEJ trajectory, a small booster stage would be needed to be included to provide that particular trajectory, as Europa Clipper was designed for a direct to Jupiter mission on SLS. The other option would be a Venus flyby, but that would have required some kind of a heat shield.

The information to support this all is in the question, but it took a bit to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

*Supplementary answer*

I was working on [an answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/59194/40257) to [Are there any studies on Mars-Earth ballistic cyclers taking Mars-gravity assist into account?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/58978/40257) and I stumbled into Earth-Mars-Earth (EME) trajectories right around the current Europa Clipper timeline. I think I can add a bit to whats happening on this kind of trajectory.

Europa Clipper is taking advantage of a small niche of EME trajectories that have a very high Earth $v_{\infty}$ upon return, at the expense of a higher than typical launch C3 to Mars:

[image: launch and arrival porkchops]

(Personal work, the gaps are because the flyby at Mars has groomed out non viable dates)

I thought it was neat how this small set of EME trajectories resulted in extremely high Earth $v_{\infty}$ that enable the trip to Jupiter.

Answer (score 0):

**Warning:** this is a speculative answer.

I sadly would not be surprised if it were a political move to "prove" to Congress the "need" of SLS instead of relying on other launchers. Unless the Sun is in between the spacecraft and the Earth, a TCM on the way to Mars is not a big issue.

According to [KSC](https://elvperf.ksc.nasa.gov/Pages/Query.aspx) (thanks Brendan Luke), a Falcon Heavy can launch almost 6.3 tons tons with $c_3=42 ~km^2/s^2$.

[image: FH]

Comment: As a post scriptum, let's note that the new policy for the Biden Admin is led by legacy aerospace corporations who seem to ignore the existence of the Falcon Heavy and Starship: https://twitter.com/SciGuySpace/status/1354888136376070147?s=20 .

Comment: https://elvperf.ksc.nasa.gov/Pages/Query.aspx is your friend here, It also suggests ~12.5 tons at a C3 of 10 km^2/s^2

Comment: @BrendanLuke15 oh this is cool, thanks! I'll fix my answer with that data