# Largest single burn spacecraft delta-v in deep space?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, history, delta-v, record

This [700 m/s maneuver](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/49824/12102) that was avoided got me thinking and then CNN's [NASA mission will zoom by asteroid before returning sample to Earth](https://edition.cnn.com/2021/01/29/world/nasa-osiris-rex-asteroid-bennu-flyby-april-scn/index.html) said:

> "Leaving Bennu's vicinity in May puts us in the 'sweet spot,' when the departure maneuver will consume the least amount of the spacecraft's onboard fuel," said Michael Moreau, OSIRIS-REx deputy project manager at NASA's Goddard Space Flight Center in Greenbelt, Maryland, in a statement.
>
> **"Nevertheless, with over 593 miles per hour (265 meters per second) of velocity change, this will be the largest propulsive maneuver conducted by OSIRIS-REx since the approach to Bennu in October 2018."**

While OSIRIS-REx's 265 m/s delta-v maneuver seems quite large, they don't state that it's the largest ever, which leads me to wonder which one was.

**Question:** What is the largest single burn spacecraft delta-v in deep space?

Please exclude 2nd stages and kick stages and consider only the final deep-space spacecraft itself. Is it one of the [flying fuel tanks](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23026/12102)'s burn to be captured by a gas giant, or is it a six month uninterrupted "burn" of DAWN's ion engine, or something else entirely?

Comment: @Prakhar please recheck the last sentence.

Comment: How about burns done while landing on the moon? I reckon those will be grestest.

Comment: I did not find figures but I think a good place to start is by looking for orbital insertions they can be rather big.

Comment: @Prakhar "...in deep space?" excludes those. Cis-lunar space where the gravity of the Moon becomes as important as the gravity o Earth is not usually considered "deep space".

Comment: @lijat thus "... of the [flying fuel tanks](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23026/12102)'s burn to be captured by a gas giant"

Answer (score 5):

The winner is [Magellan's orbital insertion at Venus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magellan_(spacecraft)#Orbital_encounter_of_Venus) at ~2.69 km/s (calculated). However, it is up for interpretation on whether or not you think Magellan's [STAR-48B](https://www.northropgrumman.com/wp-content/uploads/NG-Propulsion-Products-Catalog.pdf#page=108) counts as "*part of final deep-space spacecraft itself*". It did make the 15 month interplanetary journey to Venus, but was jettisoned after orbital insertion.

[DAWN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dawn_(spacecraft)) is a strong contender with its ion propulsion system; however, it never *continuously* thrusted more than 2.7 km/s at a time according to this statement from [Garner et al. "Ion propulsion: An enabling technology for the Dawn Mission" (2013)](http://hdl.handle.net/2014/44151):

> For the first 2.75 years of cruise to Vesta IPS was operated at full power thrusting at seven-day thrusting periods (thrust arcs) with off-times for data playbacks and command uplinks limited to approximately six to nine hours.

In total during cruise to Vesta DAWN contributed more $\Delta V$ than Magellan:

[image: DAWN timeline & delta v]

(From [Garner et al. (2013)](http://hdl.handle.net/2014/44151))

Orbital insertions at outer planets (all 3 of them; [Galileo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galileo_project), [Cassini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini%E2%80%93Huygens), [Juno](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juno_(spacecraft)#Insertion_into_Jovian_orbit)) haven't been record maneuvers because launch/throw mass constraints dictate that they insert into highly elliptical orbits to avoid requiring as huge a propellant load. All had insertion burns of well under 1 km/s.

If Magellan doesn't count then the winner is, surprisingly, [Mariner 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mariner_9) at 1.53 km/s (calculated). Mariner 9 was the first spacecraft to orbit another planet.