# How long can the dawn probe‘s ion thrusters burn?

Tags: propulsion, electric-propulsion, long-duration, dawn-mission

The title pretty much summarizes the question.

Weirdly, googling „dawn spaceprobe burn time“ and similar things didn‘t turn up anything useful (at least for me), so I was wondering if maybe someone here knows how long dawn‘s xenon reserves lasted?

Comment: related but unanswered: [Largest single burn spacecraft delta-v in deep space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/49843/12102)

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, it‘s 51,385 hours (wow!)

From NASA's [Dawn by the Numbers](https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/resources/2168/dawn-by-the-numbers/):

> Source: NASA/Jet Propulsion Laboratory-Caltech
>
> Published: November 15, 2018
>
> NASA's Dawn mission by the numbers:
>
> - **51,385 hours** of ion engine thrusting.
> - **172 GB** of science data collected.
> - **3,052 orbits** around Vesta and Ceres
> - **100,000 images** taken.
> - **4.3+ billion miles** (6.9+ billion kilometers) traveled since launch.
> - **367+ million miles** (591+ million kilometers): Farthest distance from Earth.
>
> Read More
>
> - [Dawn Mission: In Depth](https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/missions/dawn/in-depth/)
> - [More on Ceres](https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/planets/dwarf-planets/ceres/overview/)
> - [More on Vesta](https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/small-bodies/asteroids/4-vesta/in-depth/)

Comment: What's the source of this info?

Comment: @OrangeDurito NASA: https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/resources/2168/dawn-by-the-numbers/

Comment: @OrangeDurito although I did make a possibly confusing typo

Comment: @Jake It's always okay to answer your own question n SE, but it's important to make it a good quality answer, so I've move your link back into your post where it belongs, and included a block quote of the numbers so if the link rots the information is still available in the answer, thereby preventing it from being a link-only answer.